# How to debug typescript in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

I use typescript in my Ionic 2 project . How to debug my typescript files ? I try to without webpack file  , But it is not a good solution for that !!Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

To debug your application, use the keyword **debugger** in your code which will set the break point

```
function myBrokenFunction() {
      debugger;
      // do other stuff
    }
```

Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/developer-tips/) for details

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm / InteliJ [Supports Typescript debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/debugging-typescript.html). it is using a chrome extension and allow you to put breakpoints in the IDE.
[This blog post also covers it](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/09/30/how-to-debug-angular-2-with-webstorm/)

Answer (score 0):

If visual debugging is more your style you could checkout [Batarangle](https://github.com/rangle/batarangle), an Angular2 take on the Batarang browser plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack as the app bundler, instead of rollup , try to create a file on your project's root , webpack.config.js , and write this content:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

In your typescript config file tsconfig.json, yuo must have the entry :

```
"sourceMap": true
```

Comment: There is no webpack.config.js in a ionic v2 project!

Comment: just add it, you should be ready to override some default features of webpack